# draw a chart in javascript

Tags: javascript, flot

I am very new to javascript. I like to draw a chart from the following array:

```
var sampleData = [
                                    { Period: '1981', Size: 80.01 , Age: 32 },
                                    { Period: '1981', Size: 89.11, Age : 35 }];
```

I use jquery.flot.js library to draw the chart. Here is the example to draw the chart and it works fine:

```
var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5)
        d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1, d2]);
```

According to example here is my code for drawing the chart :

```
var myData1 = [];
     for (var i in sampleData) {
        myData.push( sampleData[i].Period, sampleData[i].Size);
    } 
var myData2 = [];
     for (var i in sampleData) {
        myData.push( sampleData[i].Period, sampleData[i].Age);
    }              
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [myData1, myData2 ]);
```

But with this code my chart doesnot have any line !!!

Can someone point me out where is my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
myData.push( sampleData[i].Period, sampleData[i].Size);
```

I think you want

```
myData.push( [sampleData[i].Period, sampleData[i].Size] );
```

This will create an array of arrays (where the inner arrays are x,y coordinates).

Comment: I'm surprised that `'1981'` works as an xaxis value... usually has to explicitly be numbers doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be your loops:

```
 var myData1 = [];
   for (var i in sampleData) {
     myData.push( sampleData[i].Period, sampleData[i].Size);
 } 
 var myData2 = [];
   for (var i in sampleData) {
     myData.push( sampleData[i].Period, sampleData[i].Age);
 }

 $.plot($("#placeholder"), [myData1, myData2 ]);
```

Inside each of the loops, you push the data into the `myData` array, but you define `myData1` and `myData2`, change the inside of the loop to `myData1.push` and `myData2.push` respectively.

Comment: Ok, do you see data points? I re-read your question and it sounded like you don't have a line. Also, in your loops, you write `myData.push`, when you only defined `myData1` and `myData2`, is this in your code or just your post?